# I have used uri method as intent, need to create a back button in the new activity please edit the code in android

Tags: android-intent

My code is working properly but my problem is I need to create a back button in the start activity,

```
       switch(view.getId()){

    case R.id.button2:

             Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("http://http://www.google.com/search?q=computer+science+engineering+books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&oq=computer+science+"));
            ***startActivity(i);*** 
        break;

    case R.id.button3:

         Intent j = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("http://http://www.google.com/search?q=electrical+and+electronics+engineering+books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&oq=electrical+and+electronics+engineering"));
            ***startActivity(j);***
        break;
```

When new activity starts it goes to webpage, I need to create a back button  in that webpage activity.

Answer (score 0):

i dont think its possible because webbrowser is an stand alone application and you wont be able to change or put any thing in any other application except your own applicarion. i think the better waw is to make aother activity and place a webview in that activity and place your back button in that. when new activity loads, loads your web view with the desired url. this is i think the best and easiest way to do this.